# Solving a first order nonhomogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This problem stems from using the Wronskian to solve Legendre's equation for n = 1. I eventually end up with the DE $xy' - y = \frac{C}{1-x^2}$. I am having trouble solving this, I will show my steps:
$$y-xy'=\frac{-C}{1-x^2}$$
$$(ye^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2})'=\frac{Ce^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}}{x^2-1}$$
This is where I am stuck, as integrating gives you an unsolvable integral by conventional methods (according to symbolab). I am suppose to end up with the general solution to Legendre's equation, and I believe my original DE setup is correct, so I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's a mistake in your integrating factor. Remember, the ODE should be written so that the coefficient of $\color{red}{y'}$ is $1$ (if you want to use the usual formula for the integrating factor). You did it with $y$ having coefficient $1$ instead of $y'$. In other words, you should write the ODE in the form $y' +p(x)y = q(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just figured it out actually. Just let $y=ux$, $y' = u'x + u$.
Then we have: 
$$u'x^2 + ux - ux = \frac{C}{1-x^2}$$
$$u'=\frac{-C}{x^2(x^2-1)}$$
Then use the partial fraction decomposition for the RHS and just integrate.